# Set the height of a Textview so as to enter into a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

i have a LinearLayout with contain a TextView. 
i want that the text of textView is all visible calculating the height of Layout and setting the height of Textview.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutTot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonClipBoard">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" text text text text text text text text"
        android:id="@+id/textTags"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

can you help me?

i try it:

```
final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTot);

    l.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height_ = l.getMeasuredHeight();

            final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        }
    });
```

Comment: use layout_height="wrap_content" for both linearlayout and TextView

Comment: no because the text is dynamic

Comment: also wrap_content is dynamic

Comment: yes but the height of texview must increase or decrease

Comment: and that's what wrap_content means

Comment: I solved with a library 
https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview